# Django text game trade table

Tags: python, django, algorithm

I'm creating web text game in Django. I'd like to give user option to trade his pets with bank. Exchange table is static and cannot be modified.

> 1 sheep = 6 rabbits
>
> 1 pig = 2 sheep = 12 rabbits = 1 sheep + 6 rabbits
>
> 1 cow = 3 pig = 6 sheeps = 36 rabbit etc.

Now if user have 3 pigs I'd like to show him options that he could trade 3 pigs for 1 cow or trade 1 pig for 2 sheep or 1 pig for 12 rabbits etc.
Is there any option to write this with ifs or i could do some other way ?

models.py

```
class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)  # nazwa gracza


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)  # nazwa gry
    turn = models.IntegerField(default=1)  # numer gracza ktory aktualnie rzuca
    rabbit = models.IntegerField(default=60)
    sheep = models.IntegerField(default=24)
    pig = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    cow = models.IntegerField(default=12)
    horse = models.IntegerField(default=6)
    small_dog = models.IntegerField(default=4)
    big_dog = models.IntegerField(default=2)


class GamePlayer(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Players, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    turn = models.IntegerField()
    rabbit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sheep = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pig = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cow = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    horse = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    small_dog = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    big_dog = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: what do you mean with "exchange table is static"? "to write this with ifs" where? views or template?

Comment: exchange table cannot be changed like on example above. Actually my only idea is to write ifs on template and then in view veryfing that user have enough number of animals to exchange, if he have then exchange.

Comment: can you show your models.py? depending on that we can write views

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SCSUCNiP

Comment: some details are missing, i cannot follow your logic

Comment: @doniyor what do you wanna to know I'll tried to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List item

If the table is static then it can be use as a simple dict

Here is an example code of you may approach this problem

```
from collections import Counter

# 1 sheep = 6 rabbits
# 
# 1 pig = 2 sheep = 12 rabbits = 1 sheep + 6 rabbits
# 
# 1 cow = 3 pig = 6 sheeps = 36 rabbit etc.

TABLE = {
         'rabbit': 1,
         'sheep': 6,
         'pig': 12,
         'cow': 36,
         }



def get_trades(amount, l=()):
    '''
    Recursive function that returns a list of all possible trades as tuples 
    '''
    if amount < 0 : return [()] # bad trade (not enough money)
    if amount == 0 : return [l] # bingo!!! we have a full trade possibly.
    possible_trades = []        
    animals_sorted = sorted(TABLE, key= lambda key: TABLE[key], reverse=True)
    if l: 
        animals_sorted = animals_sorted[animals_sorted.index(l[-1]):] #preventing duplicates - since order doesn't matter
    for something in animals_sorted:
        value = TABLE[something]

        trades = get_trades(amount-value, l + (something,)) #get possible trades for l+something ...
        possible_trades.extend(trades)
    return possible_trades

def get_trades_counters(amount):
    return [Counter(t) for t in get_trades(amount)]


def main():
    print(get_trades_counters(TABLE['pig']))
    print(get_trades_counters(2*TABLE['pig']))
    print(get_trades_counters(2*TABLE['cow']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's almost working good. If I `print(get_trades_counters(TABLE['sheep']))` I see at output `small_dog 1 sheep 1 rabbit 6`. I don't wanna change one sheep for 1 sheep so this should't be displayed. I don't know how this code works but it's almost this what I wanna. Thanks for help.

Comment: Read a bit about *recursion*  and also you may strip the unwanted results after applying the algorithm. I'll add a few more comments as well

Comment: Can you check i did it corectly? I modified function get_trades_counters() to remove element and return list:
`def get_trades_counters(animal, amount):
    result = [Counter(t) for t in get_trades(amount*TRADE_TABLE[animal])]
    r = []
    for i in result:
        r.append(i.most_common())
    r.remove([(animal, amount)])
    return r`

Comment: You don't need to modify it, just remove the unwanted results after calling it